# Which C++ compilers automatically define size_t without requiring a header include?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, size-t

While using the C++ compiler of Visual Studio 2013, I noticed that my code relying on **size_t** correctly compiled even without including any headers that define it (i.e. `#include <stddef.h>` or `#include <string.h>`).

I tested this because I kind of like the idea of not including a whole header just for something trivial like that; I feel like it bloats my code. I concluded that the C++ compiler of Visual Studio 2013 automatically defines the `size_t`, even without any header inclusions in the code.

While enjoying this, I started worrying about portability. Coding convenience, and feeling like my code is elegant, are things more important to me than absolute portability; but I would still like *some* portability. For example, I don't  mind using `#pragma once` since most compilers support it and header guards are a hassle (especially so in Visual Studio), but I would never resort to exporting templates just because one comiler supports it.

So, my question is, is the automatic definition of **size_t** a widespread feature offered by many compilers, or is it something specific to Microsoft's compiler?

Comment: includes don't bloat code

Comment: more than likely some of their code depends on it and it's included via another header

Comment: @pm100 I suppose you're right about that, but I just don't like the feeling of it; I prefer doing just `size_t` instead of `std::size_t`, but that would mean including my header would introduce symbols into the global namespace because it in turn includes `<stddef.h>`. I feel like I'm stepping on other people's freedom by doing that.

Comment: There's always `decltype(sizeof 1)` for those who really really hate headers ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behaviour certainly isn't widespread; both GCC and Clang require the inclusion of `<cstddef>` for `std::size_t`, or the deprecated `<stddef.h>` for `::size_t`, as the standard specifies.

Answer (score 4):

[Neither gcc nor clang contain a similar violation of the C++ standard](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bdd24050841b0c1).

Between the 3, MSVC gcc and clang are the vast majority of compilers out there.

The same is true of [icc 13.0.1](http://goo.gl/4QdF0u).

I did not try [ECG](http://comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/), feel free yourself.