# Why is size_t intrinsically defined in visual studio c++ x64

Tags: c++

This code compiles with no headers, implying that `size_t` is intrinsically defined as `unsigned long long`:

```
int main()
{
    size_t i = -1;  // i is 18446744073709551615
}
```

But [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237370/) says that `std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>` and may or may not be included in the global namespace.

However, I'm not including any headers, so where is this defined?

Further, if I defined it as a `signed int`, it also works! Note:
@user17732522 points out this is local so OK. When put in global it fails to compile.

```
int main()
{
    typedef long long int size_t;
    size_t i = -1;  // i is 1
}
```

Is this a bug, or some odd extension in Visual C++?

Comment: It doesn't compile in GCC or clang.

Comment: @interjay  Good to know.  I've been using it widely w/o `std::` Probably gets put into global from headers in my programs. So looks like a bug. Likely to keep really old programs from breaking. Not likely to cause a problem I suppose.

Comment: I suppose I could just put `typedef decltype(sizeof(int)) size_t;` in front of any code and it shouldn't cause any portability issues. Or include *cstddef* and add a using

Comment: The second snippet declares a name `size_t` local to the function. It is not related to `::size_t` or `std::size_t`.

Comment: "*However, I'm not including any headers, so where is this defined?*" - it might be defined in a **Precompiled Header** that gets included in the compile via project settings rather than by code.

Comment: @user17732522  Good point. In global if fails. That's good!

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's not using precompiled headers. And nothing in the full option list shows anything weird. However, there is something called *vcruntime.h* that seems to define it. No idea how it's getting included.

Comment: @doug VS does a lot behind the scenes for you, well hidden in Menus, inside menus, inside menus. It’s not shocking to me that they are either implicitly importing cstddef. Or have it defined intrinsic in the compiler

Comment: @Taekahn  Yeah. I looked at *cstddef* and it's not doing it or including *vcruntime.h* seems it's (vcruntime) is just getting included because it's x64.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: [Which C++ compilers automatically define size\_t without requiring a header include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543394/which-c-compilers-automatically-define-size-t-without-requiring-a-header-inclu)

Comment: As far as I can tell this behavior is not standard-conform. It should put out a diagnostic that `size_t` is not declared, although the version declaring it in global scope probably has undefined behavior, because the name `::size_t` is reserved.

Comment: @user17732522 yep. Mike Seymour's answer is good. Thanks. Looks like something VC++ has been doing for a long time behind the scenes. Definitely a dup.