# Using C++20 makes some compilations errors disappear

Tags: c++, c++20

Why does the following `main.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<size_t> order;
    reverse(order.begin(), order.end());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compile without errors with `g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp` but fails (as expected) without C++20 enabled (`g++ main.cpp`)?

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:17: error: ‘size_t’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘std::size_t’?
    5 |     std::vector<size_t> order;
      |                 ^~~~~~
      |                 std::size_t
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/vector:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/c++config.h:280:33: note: ‘std::size_t’ declared here
  280 |   typedef __SIZE_TYPE__         size_t;
      |                                 ^~~~~~
main.cpp:5:23: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    5 |     std::vector<size_t> order;
      |                       ^
main.cpp:5:23: error: template argument 2 is invalid
main.cpp:6:19: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘order’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
    6 |     reverse(order.begin(), order.end());
      |                   ^~~~~
main.cpp:6:34: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘order’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
    6 |     reverse(order.begin(), order.end());
      |                                  ^~~
main.cpp:6:5: error: ‘reverse’ was not declared in this scope
    6 |     reverse(order.begin(), order.end());
      |     ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:8:12: error: ‘EXIT_SUCCESS’ was not declared in this scope
    8 |     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

For the record, I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`.

EDIT: There are similar questions about `size_t` vs `std::size_t`, but I'm more puzzled about the `reverse` function.

Comment: [Doesn't compile even with C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/hT59KPzzv) for me.

Comment: It interestingly compiles if you switch to version [11.4](https://godbolt.org/z/WPEY84dbo)

Comment: [Which C++ compilers automatically define size_t without requiring a header include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543394/which-c-compilers-automatically-define-size-t-without-requiring-a-header-inclu)

Comment: Standard headers are allowed to include each other, and `<cstddef>` is allowed but not required to have `::size_t` as an alias for `std::size_t`.

Comment: It doesn't explain why `reverse` compiles though.

Comment: My guess would be some sort of ADL.

Comment: The code doesn't `#include` the headers that it needs, so it only compiles by accident. This isn't a C++ 20 thing, except that the underlying library header organization might have been changed when the library was updated.

Comment: I know, this is exactly what the question is about, explain the "accident"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::reverse` is found through argument dependent lookup as `std::vector::iterator` is in the same namespace.

Presumably the missing `<algorithm>` include is found indirectly through `<vector>`, adding c++20 will add more features to `<vector>` which presumably requires the inclusion of `<algorithm>`.

Note that this compiles with MSVC and clang with libc++ without needing c++20: https://godbolt.org/z/hGoj4shr3 and GCC compiles with the missing include: https://godbolt.org/z/b4jKWEo1f